# Is there a way to change the replication factor of RDDs in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

From what I understand, there are multiple copies of data in RDDs in the cluster, so that in case of failure of a node, the program can recover. However, in cases where chance of failure is negligible, it would be costly memory-wise to have multiple copies of data in the RDDs. So, my question is, is there a parameter in Spark, which can be used to reduce the replication factor of the RDDs?

Comment: Where did you read that this is the case?

Comment: What I mean is that the data is replicated in the RDDs, and not that the RDDs themselves are replicated. I have updated the post.

Comment: There is typically replication in the storage underlying input RDDs; that doesn't mean that computation will be replicated.  Either way, that's a feature of HDFS (say), not Spark.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the storage, not the computation. I want to reduce the memory used to save the RDD. By the way, what is the default replication factor?

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  The replication factor of the underlying distributed filke system doesn't impact the memory/CPU usage of Spark.

Comment: But If I use persist(MEMORY_ONLY) or cache(), the RDD is persisted in memory? No?

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure how that affects things though.  You can explicitly choose to persist on disk with replicas, but not in memory AFAIK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, note Spark does not automatically cache all your `RDD`s, simply because applications may create many `RDD`s, and not all of them are to be reused. You have to call `.persist()` or `.cache()` on them.

You can set the storage level with which you want to persist an `RDD` with
`myRDD.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)`. `.cache()` is a shorthand for `.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)`.

The default storage level for `persist` is indeed `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY` for an `RDD` in Java or Scala – but usually differs if you are creating a `DStream` (refer to your `DStream` constructor API doc). If you're using Python, it's `StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER`.

The [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) details a number of storage levels and what they mean, but they're fundamentally a configuration shorthand to point Spark to an object which extends the [`StorageLevel` class](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/StorageLevel.scala). You can thus define your own with a replication factor of up to 40.

Note that of the various predefined storage levels, some keep a single copy of the `RDD`. In fact, that's true of all of those which name isn't postfixed with `_2` (except `NONE`):

- DISK_ONLY
- MEMORY_ONLY
- MEMORY_ONLY_SER
- MEMORY_AND_DISK
- MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER
- OFF_HEAP

That's one copy per medium they employ, of course, if you want a single copy overall, you have to choose a single-medium storage level.

Answer (score 1):

As huitseeker said unless you specifically ask Spark to persist an RDD and specify a StorageLevel that uses a replication, it won't have multiple copies of the partitions of an RDD.

What spark does do is keep a lineage of how a specific piece of data was calculated so that when/if a node fails it only repeats processing of relevant data that is needed to get to the lost RDD partitions - In my experience this mostly works though on occasion it is faster to restart the job then let it recover

Comment: If a node fails, spark will only `recompute` the RDD partitions lost on this node, but where does the data source needed in the `recompution` process come from ? Do you mean its parent RDD is still there when the node fails?What if the RDD that lost some partitions didn't have parent RDD ?

Comment: Spark keeps lineage for the RDD so it knows to reconstruct what's needed https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-rdd-lineage.html