# How to stop Spark RDD mapPartitions duplicating data in cluster?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, partition

We discovered the issue with duplication due to an external dependency getting called numerous times, a value greater than actual size of the RDD. The result of the transformation is a consolidated RDD with size == input RDD size, I suspect this could be the reason why the problem is undiscoverable and there aren't many solutions documented online. We tried a couple of approaches, mentioned below -

Approach 1: Using mapPartitionsWithIndex function with persistPartition = true, result was the same - duplication of data.

Approach 2: Another stackoverflow solution recommended calling  rdd.cache() before the mapPartition transformation since the cause was due to lazy evaluation and cache can invoke an immediate transformation. This seemed to resolve the issue but caching led to other memory related exceptions.

rdd = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(partitionFunction, true);

Results from spark worker nodes in a 4 node cluster with RDD having size 1000

2019-08-11 13:48:47,487 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO   - Found 215 records in Partition 3
2019-08-11 13:48:47,634 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO   - Found 203 records in Partition 0
2019-08-11 13:49:44,472 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO   - Found 177 records in Partition 2
2019-08-11 13:49:46,252 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO   - Found 201 records in Partition 4
2019-08-11 13:49:44,537 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO   - Found 203 records in Partition 0
2019-08-11 13:48:47,170 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO   - Found 204 records in Partition 1
2019-08-11 13:48:47,410 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO   - Found 177 records in Partition 2
2019-08-11 13:49:16,875 [Executor task launch worker-0] INFO   - Found 201 records in Partition 4

Total records across partitions: 1581

Any suggestions from the community on solving this issue? TIA

Comment: consider setting the storage level explicitly, here's a link on how to set it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624622/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-replication-factor-of-rdds-in-spark)

Comment: Sure, I can do that but doesn't seem like a legitimate solution, only a workaround.